# WebVR supported, but no VRDisplays found, suddnly

Tags: webvr

When I develop webVr content using A-frame  , web vr work probably with oculus rift using nightly browser (powered by firefox)

Then after 1 day I restart my computer , Then non of web vr experience work (developed by me or by other ) in nightly browser . 
when i test using 
https://webvr.info/samples/test-vr-links.html
The message "WebVR supported, but no VRDisplays found."
so i have problem i don't know where it .

->then I install  firefox developer edition (it support web vr)
and I try test , it work probably then crash message from browser appears

so what can I do with this problem ? any solution ?

Note :
-I use web vr and I try it many times this problem doesn't appear
- all oculus experiences from store work
-actually I uninstalled  and installed Nightly ,this step doesn't solve the problem .

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever tried installing [WebVR Emulation](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webvr-api-emulation/gbdnpaebafagioggnhkacnaaahpiefil) plugin in your Chrome Browser?
With the Emulation plugin, you don't even need the VR device like Oculus Rift, which kind of handy for development directly on desktop non-nightly browser.