# How do I troubleshoot Oculus in Firefox WebVR?

Tags: firefox, virtual-reality, aframe, oculus, webvr

I'm currently using Oculus Rift + Touch in A-Frame (0.6.1). I haven't found any online forum on where to ask. I've tried using Firefox 55 (Which comes with WebVR), but it doesn't detect the Rift.

I can use Firefox Nightly, but it's very unstable, and it comes with different problems. My most recent one, is that the whole screen goes blank whenever I try to enter VR mode. The display is seen in the headset, and the app is able to work flawlessly. But I can't go back to Firefox and check the devtools (which is annoying).

How can I troubleshoot the Oculus Rift so I can connect it to a stable version of Firefox, such as 55?

Tried checking this:
[WebVR supported, but no VRDisplays found, suddnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43830637/webvr-supported-but-no-vrdisplays-found-suddnly)

But it didn't help.

Comment: You could check if the problem is listed in the current [buglist](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=%5Bwebvr%5D) for Firefox and [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Core&component=General&status_whiteboard=[webvr]&cc=kgilbert@mozilla.com) if it's not present. [This](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1298612) bug seems to be related and still active.

Comment: Also sometimes it's related to drivers or Oculus updates. I haven't tried Firefox + Rift in a while though.

Comment: @ngokevin Interesting. So that means it's not a WebVR thing, but Oculus, right? Thanks for the response.

Comment: Not Oculus specifically, maybe Nvidia drivers sometimes as well. Could just be Firefox as well. Don't know. If you go to about:config, double check that oculus vr is enabled.

Comment: @ngokevin: OMG!!! THAT WAS *IT*. Firefox's had it disabled (oculus vr was set to false) !!! OMG OMG OMG OMG It's now working, *flawlessly*. Please, post it as an answer so I can mark it as accepted!! (Cheers!)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with Firefox 57, and the Oculus. Downgrading to Firefox 56 seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check about:config in Firefox and make sure the VR flags are enabled (specifically the Oculus one). Sometimes it may be disabled for some reason.